# How to reference self in a Subscriber in Combine in Swift

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, publisher, subscriber, combine

Just getting to grips with Combine and have come across an issue where I need to call a method in my class when it receives a value from a `Publisher`, in this case a `Notification` from `NotificationCenter`...

Here's the subscription...

```
let subscribe = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name(rawValue: "LocalTalkNotificationReceivedData"), object: nil)
    .map( {
        ($0.object as! Data)
    } )
    .sink(receiveValue: {
        self.interpretIncoming(data: $0)
    })
```

What I get told by the compiler is `Use of unresolved identifier 'self'`.
It's late, I'm kinda tired, anyone got an idea?
Xcode 11 beta 5 on Catalina beta 5 btw...

Complete file:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

public class MessageData: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
public var peerData: [Peer] = [Peer]()
public var messageData: [Message] = [Message]()
public var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
let subscribe = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: Notification.Name(rawValue: "LocalTalkNotificationReceivedData"), object: nil)
    .map( {
        ($0.object as! Data)
    } )
    .sink(receiveValue: {
        self.interpretIncoming(data: $0)
    })

init() {
    self.setupDummyData()
}

private func setupDummyData() {
    self.peerData = self.load("peerData.json")
    self.messageData = self.load("messageData.json")
}

func addMessage(message: String, sender: MessageSource, name: String) {
    let newMessage = Message(id: Date().hashValue,
                             content: message,
                             source: sender,
                             correspondent: name)
    self.messageData.append(newMessage)
    self.objectWillChange.send()
}

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String, as type: T.Type = T.self) -> T {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}

func interpretIncoming(data sent: Data) {
    do {
        let receivedTransmission = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(sent) as! [String: Any]
        self.addMessage(message: receivedTransmission["messagePayload"] as! String,
                        sender: .them,
                        name: receivedTransmission["messageSender"] as! String)
    } catch {
        print("FAILED DECODING THING")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Show more code. Whether self exists depends on where your code is. Nothing to do with Combine.

Comment: OK, added the complete file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in your question is a red herring except the word `self`. You are saying:

```
class MessageData: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    let subscribe = ... self ...
}
```

You cannot mention `self` in the initializer of a property declaration, because `self` is what we are in the process of initializing; there is no `self` yet.

A simple solution here might be to change `let subscribe` to `lazy var subscribe`, but then you would have to ask for the value of `subscribe` in your actual code in order to get the initialization to happen. However, there are many other possible approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Self doesn’t exist in the context you are calling. A number of ways to remedy this include defining interpretIncoming as a closure variable or make  it a class method and call as needed.

Comment: Interesting. Making it a class method doesn't help as I am mutating the state of the instance. Could you tell me a little more about the other suggestion, I didn't quite understand what you meant?